# app crash on button click when spinner getting populated dynamically

Tags: android, validation, spinner

****SOLVED****

I just had to use button set enable property correctly. I was defining the enable property false before the declaration of button . It was a very silly mistake.

---

****QUESTION****

I have an android with three spinners getting their data dynamically using rest services. The problem is if i click the save button in the bottom while the spinners are still being loaded. the app crashes. what i am trying to achieve is a method to disable my button click till spinners load their value. I tried setEnabled property & set clickable property. but none helped. i need help in this kind of validation .

```
else if(spinner1.getSelectedItem().toString().trim().equals(""))
         {  

            Toast.makeText(HourlyEntry.this,"Please wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT) .show();  
             return false;  
        }
```

**Logcat**

[image]

Comment: post your logcat then.

Comment: it just says uncaught exception . no long red color errors in the logcat..  It says uncaught exception.  this is the only reason m having trouble

Comment: what is this? post your all logcat for better understanding.

Comment: `try { things(); } catch(Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }` Logcat will show what's wrong in this part.

Comment: sir its in try catch block only. it's crashing bcoz spinners are loading. after the spinenrs have loaded their value. everything works just fine

Comment: What i am looking for is a method to disable my button click or its enabled stage till spinners get their value.

Comment: Can anyone help pls.. this is a major bug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the `enable` state of the button. You must be declaring it before declaration.

```
Spinner spinner1;
Spinner1.enable =true
```